# Unit-Testing Flask application views & dialogs

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, nose

I am new to Flask and have recently started working on a project. After I've fixed some issues related to dialogs and views the client asked to write unittests to verify the resolutions. I've gone through some already written tests but they mostly just check the status code of http response, like this:

```
def test_home_page(self):
    rv = self.client.get('/home')
    self.assertEqual(rv._status_code, 200, rv._status_code)
```

Lets say my application has some hyper-links and on clicking these links, different dialog boxes open (e.g. on clicking Forgot Password link, reset password dialog-box). Can we write a test to check if it's opening properly or not?

Similarly on entering different inputs (like leaving the email adress blank, entering invalid / non-existing / valid+existing email addresses) different flash messages appear. How can we write a test to verify that the appropriate flash message is displayed? I guess we've to check this in sessions?

Looking for help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What dialog functionalities? Can you be a bit more descriptive? Post some code example. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

What your really need is integration tests and not unit tests to be able to that. You should check out [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which is a browser automation API that can help you write this kind of tests

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can we write integration tests to be run with nose or the nose is just for unit-testing?